# Will a Delta to Wye transformer cause a huge loss to Generator output voltage?

Tags: voltage, transformer

I'm planning to convert my three phase supply to a single phase supply. To achieve this I'm planning to use a delta to wye transformer. My major concern would be, will the generator output voltage suffer a great loss.

Comment: The generator output voltage should be unaffected - the voltage out of the transformer will depend on the specs of the transformer.

Comment: Here is a deal, I tried to connect a 110/240 V 1 Kva transfomer to the generator. the generator simply stops spinning. Its causes the generator output voltage drops drastically, as the rotor seems to be locked.

Comment: Your name sounds familiar. Are you the one who cannot consider reconfiguring the generator to Wye for some reason? I think that is possible, though I don't know much about generators. What is the load? Is it an electric motor? What is the rated power consumption of the load? And what about the generator? What is the rated output of the generator? Finally, in your comment, was this a delta-wye transfomer or a single-phase transformer? Are you planning to connect your load to just one phase of the Wye? That would be an unbalanced load, wouldn't it?

Comment: A Delta to Wye transformer will still leave yhou with three-phase power.  Are you shorting the secondary terminals of the transformer?  What is the power rating of the generator?

Comment: @mkeith yeap. I have ordered a transfomer to convert my delta to wye. so that i could load the generator much safely. Loading the delta line to line causes an unbalanced loading. the rated ouput is 1000 W. nope in wye if load a single phase to netural, it would be fine.

Comment: @PeterBennett connecting to delta line to line is giving me a headache. so in Wye connection,I'm expecting a phase to neutral option.

Comment: If you connect a single-phase load to a single phase on the Wye output, aren't you going to have the exact same problem?

Comment: @mkeith that's the thing I'm worried off. Will my generator stop turning. Right now every time without transformer direct loading is causing the rotor to lock up. Bear in mind that a 60 W load is connected to a 1000 W generator.

Comment: If your end goal is to power 60W only, maybe you should get some kind of electronic phase converter.

Comment: I assume this generator is driven by a small gasoline (petrol) engine - if a 60 watt load causes the engine to stall, I expect you have a problem with the engine controls - the throttle is not opening when the engine slows due to the added load.

Comment: @mkeith my goal is 300 W. For testing purpose I used a resistive 60W load.

Comment: @PeterBennett I'm using exhaust wind to drive the generator. Just now I tried with a 10 W load at 180 V generated. Guess what the generator stalled and stop. Looks like my input torque is not enough, even tough at no load its generating about 180 V to 240 V.

Answer (score 1):

> My major concern would be, will the generator output voltage suffer a
>   great loss.

No, if you do it properly and don't draw too much load power because you will be imbalancing the generator. Why not use a single phase transformer?

Comment: Will a single phase transformer effect the output voltage. As if would it act like a load on its own. As at no load condition the output reads up to 240 V, right at the moment when I load a 10 W resistive load, the generator stops. Thus I'm worried the transformer would not work if it were installed.

Comment: A transformer: power out = power in minus losses. Losses should be a few percent.

Comment: Have you tested the generator with a proper delta load to verify that it works at all? Maybe the generator has a problem. You could rig up a balanced delta load with some incandescent lamps of some sort. Based on what you are seeing, something seems very wrong. Is the generator totally floating with respect to ground or is it grounded to Earth in some fashion? Are the various loads you have attached for test purposes grounded in any way? Maybe there is an earth ground connection that is causing problems.

Comment: @mkeith, indeed I never taught of it in that way. Today I should try it then. So far only incandescent light is use but it is unbalanced loading tough. My grounding is floating, I used the generator body as grounding point for now. I also tried to connect the load across two phases. still same problem arises. the lowest load that i have used so far is 10 W 33 ohm resistive load. Im guessing that my torque generated is not enough